# How to set state between tabbar tabs in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have tackeled without any success with problem...

My main page is stateful class with tabbar with two tabs. First tab has some text from global variables and couple of textfields that also are prefilled  with global variables.
Second tab has a button and ontap it calls setstate that changes variables, that are used on first tab and then animates to first tab.
My problem is that first tabs text doesnt change to new value. At the same time textfields will have new values. If i add print command before returning text on first tab, code will print out new values, but state for text is not set, at the same time textfields state will be set.
Its not possible at moment to add code, but i hope i described mu problem good enough.

Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

There is a really elaborate explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70884353/380316).

Bottom line, there is a race condition between `setState` and `animateTo`, and he suggests breaking it so:

```
onPressed: () {
  setProduct();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {         
     animateToFirstPage;
  })    
}
```

Verified it worked for me, and without creepy .sleep solutions

Answer (score 1):

I tryed many things and now i got strange working solution that makes what i want.
If i just set new variables and after that let tabcontroller to animate dirst page, pages state will not be set, but if i add small delay, then it works like i want. If anyone could explain why, i would be really thankful.

```
onPressed: () {
  setProduct();
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), animateToFirstPage);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple state management solution. Where both tabs can listen and modify the values you want. Without code is hard to demonstrate. But you can't simply change the state of a widget from another widget, using provider would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

To update and listen to the change, use `StreamController` and `StreamBuilder`. You can put the first tab in a widget combined with `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to prevent it from reloading as well. I created a simple app for demonstration:

Full example:
**main.dart**

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController<String>();
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample App'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        labelColor: Colors.red,
        tabs: [Tab(text: 'Tab 1'), Tab(text: 'Tab 2')],
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          FirstTab(_streamController),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: TextButton(
                child: Text('Press me'),
                onPressed: () {
                  final _someText =
                      'Random number: ' + Random().nextInt(100).toString();
                  _streamController.add(_someText);
                  _tabController.animateTo(0);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final StreamController _streamController;

  FirstTab(this._streamController);

  @override
  _FirstTabState createState() => _FirstTabState();
}

class _FirstTabState extends State<FirstTab>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<String>(
            initialData: 'Empty text',
            stream: widget._streamController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text(snapshot.data);
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```