# TabBarView page not rebuilding correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to display the tab number on each page of a `TabBarView`, by reading the index of its `TabController`. For some reason though, the value does not seem to update correctly visually, even though the correct value is printed in the logs.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  _back() {
    if (_tabController!.index > 0) {
      _tabController!.animateTo(_tabController!.index - 1);

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  _next() {
    if (_tabController!.index < _tabController!.length - 1) {
      _tabController!.animateTo(_tabController!.index + 1);

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Widget _tab(int index) {
    var value = "Page $index:   ${_tabController!.index + 1} / ${_tabController!.length}";
    print(value);

    return Row(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _back,
          child: const Text("Back"),
        ),
        Text(value,
          style: const TextStyle(
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _next,
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          _tab(1),
          _tab(2),
          _tab(3),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

When navigating from index 0 to index 1, the following is printed in the logs, as expected:

```
I/flutter (25730): Page 1:   2 / 3
I/flutter (25730): Page 2:   2 / 3
I/flutter (25730): Page 3:   2 / 3
```

However, what is actually displayed is `Page 2:   1 / 3`

I have tried using `UniqueKey` as well as calling `setState` on the next frame, but it doesn't make a difference. Calling `setState` with a hardcoded delay seems to work, but it also seems wrong.

Why is what's printed in the logs different to what's being displayed, considering that all tabs are rebuilt when setState is called? Assuming it has something to do with the `PageView`/`Scrollable`/`Viewport` widgets that make up the `TabBarView`, but what exactly is going on? Notice how even when going from page 1 to page 2 and then to page 3, none of the values on any of the pages are being updated, so even the on-screen widgets aren't rebuilding correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am finally able to answer my own question. This odd behaviour is explained by the internal logic of the `_TabBarViewState`. The `TabBarView` uses a `PageView` internally, which it animates based on changes to the `TabController` index. Here is a snippet of that logic:

```
final int previousIndex = _controller!.previousIndex;
if ((_currentIndex! - previousIndex).abs() == 1) {
  _warpUnderwayCount += 1;
  await _pageController.animateToPage(_currentIndex!, duration: kTabScrollDuration, curve: Curves.ease);
  _warpUnderwayCount -= 1;
  return Future<void>.value();
}
```

Note that it keeps track of whether an animation is in progress with the `_warpUnderwayCount` variable, which will get a value of `1` as soon as we call `animateTo()` on the `TabController`.

Additionally, the `_TabBarViewState` maintains a `_children` list of widgets representing each page, which is first created when the `TabBarView` is initialized, and can later be updated only by the `_TabBarViewState` itself by calling its `_updateChildren()` function:

```
void _updateChildren() {
  _children = widget.children;
  _childrenWithKey = KeyedSubtree.ensureUniqueKeysForList(widget.children);
}
```

The `_TabBarViewState` also overrides the default behaviour of the `didUpdateWidget` function:

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(TabBarView oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget.controller != oldWidget.controller)
    _updateTabController();
  if (widget.children != oldWidget.children && _warpUnderwayCount == 0)
    _updateChildren();
}
```

Note that even though we provide a new list of `children` from our parent stateful widget by calling `setState()` just after `animateTo()`, that list of `children` will be ignored by the `TabBarView` because `_warpUnderwayCount` will have a value of `1` at the point that `didUpdateWidget` is called, and therefore `_updateChildren()` will not be called as per the internal logic shown above.

I believe this is a constraint of the `TabBarView` widget that has to do with its complexity in terms of coordinating with its internal `PageView` as well as with an optional `TabBar` widget with which it shares a `TabController`.

In terms of a solution, given that rebuilding the whole `TabBarView` by updating its `Key` would cancel the animation, and that setting new `children` by calling `setState()` after calling `animateTo()` is ignored if done while the page change animation is still running, I can only think of calling `setState()` after saving all the variables required for rebuilding the `children` and **before** `animateTo()` is called on the next frame. If it is called within the same frame, the `children` will still not update because `didUpdateWidget` will still be called after the animation starts. Here is the code from my question, updated with the proposed solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? _tabController;
  int _newIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  _back() {
    if (_tabController!.index > 0) {
      _newIndex = _tabController!.index - 1;

      setState(() {});

      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        _tabController!.animateTo(_newIndex);
      });
    }
  }

  _next() {
    if (_tabController!.index < _tabController!.length - 1) {
      _newIndex = _tabController!.index + 1;

      setState(() {});

      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        _tabController!.animateTo(_newIndex);
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _tab(int index) {
    var value = "Page $index:   ${_newIndex + 1} / ${_tabController!.length}";
    print(value);

    return Row(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _back,
          child: const Text("Back"),
        ),
        Text(value,
          style: const TextStyle(
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _next,
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            _tab(1),
            _tab(2),
            _tab(3),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work on  swap.

Comment: What do you mean by swap?

Comment: Try  changing tab with swapping

Comment: Do you mean swiping? Indeed that would not update anything as there wouldn't be anything to call `setState`. This is fine for my particular use case because we disable swiping and use back and forward buttons, but I will clarify that in my answer or try to get that working too.

Comment: Wonderful  Elaborate and works without breakin the race condition with sleeping as suggested in other answers

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of flutter animatedTo method description: animatedTo immediately sets index and previous index and then plays the animation from its current value to index.

Once the _tab method is called, the widget that returns from it is now in the widget tree.

Whenever the build method is run again then its appearance will change.

Every time the _tab method is called, the part of the code that does not return the widget runs again, and return widget which is already in the widget tree.
But it is necessary to run the build method again for the widget to change.

The build is called when the widget is built for the first time. But after that, it is necessary to re-run the build method with setState.

I convert your tab navigation buttons to Widget class. We can more easily understand the comparison with the _tab method and Widget class.

When navigating from index 0 to index 1,2,3 the following is printed in the logs:
flutter: Page 0:   1 / 3
flutter: Page 0:   1 / 3

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TestMyApp());
}

class TestMyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestMyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  _tab(1),
                  _tab(2),
                  _tab(3),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: TabNavigationWidget(tabController: _tabController!)),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _tab(int index) {
    return Text('$index');
  }
}

class TabNavigationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TabController tabController;

  TabNavigationWidget({Key? key, required this.tabController})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var value = "Page :   ${tabController.index + 1} / ${tabController.length}";
    print(value);

    return Row(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _back,
          child: Text("Back ${tabController.index}"),
        ),
        Text(
          value,
          style: const TextStyle(),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _next,
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _back() {
    if (tabController.index > 0) {
      tabController.animateTo(tabController.index - 1);
    }
  }

  _next() {
    if (tabController.index < tabController.length - 1) {
      tabController.animateTo(tabController.index + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend to you use widgets classes instead of _tab() methods. Your _tab methods build 3 times when the setState method is called.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I am aware of solutions that require calling setState with a delay, whether that's hardcoded or triggered by the tab controller listener. But you did not answer the question of why it behaves this way. Yes it builds 3 times because it builds all tabs every time setState is called. Why would the animation end have anything to do with the wrong values being displayed even though the correct values are printed in the logs, and all 3 tabs are being rebuilt?

Comment: I have noticed that you have updated your answer, but you have refactored the code such that the values displayed on each page are static, which is not my use case. My use case and question are rather simple - the content on each page depends on the controller index, so why does it not update correctly visually when I change page even though I am rebuilding the entire widget hierarchy, which is rebuilt correctly according to the logs?

Comment: You are returning the widget from the function. Once the widget is built (located to widget tree), if you call that function again, other codes will still work, except for the widget's build function.
You are changing the value of the variable in the function, but the widget needs to be rebuilt so that the new value appears on the screen.
Calling the function again does not make the widget you return from the function build from scratch again.
The problem comes from not calling the widget's build function. Only flutter can call this or with setState we can call it.

Comment: You are incorrect - the widget returned by the `_tab()` function is rebuilt at the point it is being called from the build function of `MyHomePage`. Simply replacing a widget in your hierarchy with a function that returns the same widget does not change it into a stateful widget that requires its own setState - it's just a different way of returning a new instance of that widget. You can check this by replacing the `_tab()` function calls in the build function in my code sample with the actual widget it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stream to listen for tab index change when switching pages. Update the index when changing page.

```dart
final _tabPageIndicator = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
Stream<int> get getTabPage => _tabPageIndicator.stream;

...

// Update tab index on Stream
_tabPageIndicator.sink.add(_tabController!.index + 1);
```

Then using StreamBuilder, this gets rebuild when there's a change on the Stream it's listening to. There's no need to use `setState()` to rebuild the Widgets inside StreamBuilder.

```dart
StreamBuilder<int>(
  stream: getTabPage,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
      tabIndex = snapshot.data!;
    }
    return Text(
      'Page $index: [$tabIndex / ${_tabController!.length}]',
      style: const TextStyle(),
    );
 }
),
```

[image: Demo]

Complete Sample

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? _tabController;
  int tabIndex = 1;

  final _tabPageIndicator = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  Stream<int> get getTabPage => _tabPageIndicator.stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );

    // Update tab index on Stream
    _tabPageIndicator.sink.add(_tabController!.index + 1);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    // Close Stream when not in use
    _tabPageIndicator.close();
  }

  _back() {
    if (_tabController!.index > 0) {
      _tabController!.animateTo(_tabController!.index - 1);

      // setState(() {
      // });

      // Update tab index on Stream
      _tabPageIndicator.sink.add(_tabController!.index + 1);
    }
  }

  _next() {
    if (_tabController!.index < _tabController!.length - 1) {
      _tabController!.animateTo(_tabController!.index + 1);

      // setState(() {
      // });

      // Update tab index on Stream
      _tabPageIndicator.sink.add(_tabController!.index + 1);
    }
  }

  Widget _tab(int index) {
    var value =
        "Page $index:   ${_tabController!.index + 1} / ${_tabController!.length}";
    debugPrint(value);

    return Row(
      children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _back,
          child: const Text("Back"),
        ),
        // StreamBuilder rebuilds every time there's a change on Stream
        StreamBuilder<int>(
            stream: getTabPage,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                tabIndex = snapshot.data!;
              }
              return Text(
                'Page $index: [$tabIndex / ${_tabController!.length}]',
                style: const TextStyle(),
              );
            }),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _next,
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            _tab(1),
            _tab(2),
            _tab(3),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer my question. Why does setState not result in the expected result?

Comment: That's because the tab page switches when `setState()` was used. Calling `setState()` doesn't rebuild all the TabBarView children. This is evident on the AppBar where text gets updated with `AppBar(title: Text('${widget.title} ${_tabController!.index+1}'))`. On the other hand, the value on the Text can be updated if the page doesn't switch when `setState()` is called.

Comment: But why would `setState()` not rebuild all the children? The logs indicate otherwise. There's also going from page 2 to page 3 where the text on page 2 still displays '1/3', so not even the visible children are being rebuilt? You also mentioned not being able to update the text if the page change doesn't happen when `setState()` is called. I'd be ok with either of these answers as long as you point me to the part of Flutter code that's responsible for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I know too little about `widget tree` feel free to correct and update the answer.

All tabs are building initially, while the `_tabController!.index` is `0`. `_next` method does to wait for `animateTo` to finish the animation, then call `setState`. Using `setState` rebuild the UI under `build` but the `TabBarView` is not rebuilding until we are telling it that it is having changes.

> **widget tree** is smart enough while updating the UI. -

While creating a [widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro), without providing [key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html) it generates `objectRuntimeType` key, and doesn't change(same for providing key) on calling `setState`.

While here, update is depending on key, and widget tree(key) is not different for `TabBarView` and `TabBarView` is thinking nothing happen to me, we can't see any update on UI.

Then next comes by [adding listener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/addListener.html)

> Register a closure to be called when the object changes.

We can add listener on [`TabController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) to listen changes and inside `setState` to update the UI. You can also remove `setState` from `_back` and `_next` methods.

```dart
_tabController = TabController(
  length: 3,
  vsync: this,
)..addListener(() {
    setState(() {});
  });
```

Or just

> Use `index` instead of `_tabController!.index` while both responsibility is same inside Row.

Comment: Please read the comments on the other answers - none of them provided any good explanation as to why the rebuild is not working as expected. Your solution fixes the rebuild, but it is not acceptable as it removes the page change animation.

Comment: Update the snippet with another solution and animation works here.

Comment: This does work, as a result of calling `setState` with a delay - a while after `animateTo` was called. As mentioned in the question, I am aware that calling `setState` with a delay works, the question is WHY - how is this different to calling `setState` just after `animateTo`? Also, this results in the page being rebuilt only after it has been fully animated to, which might not be ideal depending on the use case - the intent is to rebuild it as soon as `animateTo` is called such that the rebuilt widget is animated into view.

Comment: what about using `index` instead of `_tabController!.index` while both responsibility is same inside Row.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean - do you mean I should maintain a different stateful `index` parameter that tracks the value of `_tabController!.index` and use that instead?

Comment: I am referring to `_tabController!.index` use cases

Comment: That doesn't work for my use case because I have conditionally hidden pages and as such the index of each page would not match with what is displayed to the user. I therefore need to dynamically calculate the page number as displayed to the user based on the `_tabController.index` and a few other variables

Comment: In this case, I will use state-managent to provide the index

Comment: Stateful widgets are a form of state-management, changing to a different state-management approach would not change the outcome. I have now found the reason myself - please check my answer.

Comment: Yap, as you said about complex structure, that's why I mentioned that, else I will just pass index or listener